# How to make a datepicker the minimum day in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want that the user can't choose previous dates, I'm using the .min function but it doesn't do anything. If you could help me.

```
function deshabilitarFechasAnterior(){
const inputFecha=document.querySelector('#fecha');
const fechaAhora= new Date(); 
const year=fechaAhora.getFullYear();
const mes=fechaAhora.getMonth()+1; 
const dia=fechaAhora.getDate()+ 1;  
const fechaDeshabilitar=`${year}-${mes}-${dia}`;
inputFecha.min=fechaDeshabilitar;
    
}
```

Comment: `min` has to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` .... you set it to `2022-5-11` ... you need `2022-05-11` - so `mes=(fechaAhora.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0');`

Comment: Is the minimum supposed to be *tomorrow*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Using Javascript**

```js
function deshabilitarFechasAnterior() {
  const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha');
  // To set a custom date as a minimum date, create date object for that date 
  // const fechaAhora = new Date("2022-05-11");
  const fechaAhora = new Date(); // Default today's date
  const year = fechaAhora.getFullYear();
  const mes = (fechaAhora.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const dia = (fechaAhora.getDate()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const fechaDeshabilitar = `${year}-${mes}-${dia}`;
  inputFecha.setAttribute("min", fechaDeshabilitar);
}

deshabilitarFechasAnterior();
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" />
```

**Using `HTML` by adding min/max attributes.**

```html
<input id="fecha" type="date" min="2022-05-10" max="2022-05-25" />
```

Comment: Apologies, that was just a demo. Updated now.

Comment: what happens on the last day of any month?

Comment: so, what if OP really does want `min` to be tomorrow, and not today? eventually you'll end up with code that looks exactly like mine :p

Comment: `const dia=fechaAhora.getDate()+ 1; ` I believe this was not correct in the post. Should be date and not date + 1 so that user cannot pick yesterday or before dates.

Comment: what has yesterday got to do with adding one to today? without +1 min is today, with +1 min is tomorrow (a perfectly valid minimum!!)

Comment: It's mentioned in the post. `I want that the user can't choose previous dates`

Comment: If you want to set a custom min date. `const fechaAhora = new Date("2022-05-11");`

Comment: I know how dates work - OP's code implies the minimum is tomorrow - which is easily achieved - as opposed to the custom hard coded date you now propose!!

Comment: OP might have assumed date to be 0 indexed like month. Not sure though :)

Comment: So, like I said, no clue how Date works - she had a similar issue using jqueery date picker and learned nothing :p

Comment: I apologize for the errors. I'm still learning, so it's normal to make them. Thank you very much for replying

Comment: user PR7, I also added the +1 because I am practicing a website for a spa and normally the users do not ask for an appointment for the same day but for later days. But I want to know your opinion since you know the context I should leave the +1 or not? I look forward to hearing from you

Comment: @KenlymarParedes I think adding `+1` to date is not required because then the customer will not be able to book an appointment for the same day even if they want to as today's date will be disabled. Removing `+1` from date gives customers flexibility to choose today or future appointment.

Answer (score 0):

The format for min (and max) is yyyy-mm-dd ... since May is a single digit (5), the `min` is being ignored

you want `min` to be `2022-05-11` not `2022-5-11`

Simplest fix to your code is by using `toString` and `padStart` for both month and day component

Note, added one day (like your code does) BEFORE getting year/month/day ... since your way of doing it would fail on the last day of the month for obvious reasons - since there is no 32nd of May for example!!

Of course, if "min" date is supposed to be today, simply DONT include that one line of code - your code implies it should be tomorrow (albeit done incorrectly) but your question states "previous dates", which implies TODAY is a valid choice - so, you must decide if that one line is included or not, since your question implies BOTH

```js
function deshabilitarFechasAnterior() {
  const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha');
  const fechaAhora = new Date();
  // the next line makes the minimum date TOMORROW
  fechaAhora.setDate(fechaAhora.getDate() + 1);
  const year = fechaAhora.getFullYear();
  const mes = (fechaAhora.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const dia = (fechaAhora.getDate()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const fechaDeshabilitar = `${year}-${mes}-${dia}`;
  inputFecha.min = fechaDeshabilitar;



}
deshabilitarFechasAnterior();
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" />
```

Alternative - this is how I would go about it

Take advantage of the fact that `fr-CA` date string is `yyyy-mm-dd`

```js
function deshabilitarFechasAnterior() {
  const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha');
  const fechaAhora = new Date();
  // the next line makes the minimum date TOMORROW
  fechaAhora.setDate(fechaAhora.getDate() + 1);
  inputFecha.min = fechaAhora.toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');

}
deshabilitarFechasAnterior();
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I am making a website for a spa and I added the +1 to the day because normally the user does not ask for an appointment for today, it is always days later. Anyway I want to hear your opinion about it, would you recommend me to remove the +1 or not?

Comment: I don't have an opinion on your business logic @KenlymarParedes - I assume you know what you want, which is why I posted the answer using the logic you were trying to use in your question. As you can see, it's one line you can either include or not - you could even conditionally add 1 day, for instance, if it's before midday you may allow today, but after midday you don't want today allowed - what you do with that one line is irrelevant to the mistakes in your code

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```js
const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha')

deshabilitarFechasAnterior();

function deshabilitarFechasAnterior()
  {
  let dateMin = new Date()   
  dateMin.setMinutes(dateMin.getMinutes() - dateMin.getTimezoneOffset())
  
  inputFecha.value =   // to set default value too... 
  inputFecha.min   = dateMin.toISOString().split('T')[0]
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" />
```

If you don't want to code anything with the time zone offset,
the Html5 do it for you:

```js
const inputFecha = document.querySelector('#fecha')

deshabilitarFechasAnterior();

function deshabilitarFechasAnterior()
  {
  inputFecha.valueAsDate = new Date()   
  inputFecha.min         = inputFecha.value
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" />
```

Comment: that works OK ... except when `toISOString` results in a Date that is different to your timezone .... like between midnight and 10AM for me, since my timzeone is UTC+10

Comment: @bravo , that's right, corrected, just substract  the  Time zone Offset

Comment: how wonderful would it be if Date had a toLocalISOString method - it doesn't (in case you - or someone reading the comment in the future - thought I was implying otherwise)